# What is the cardinality of $\Bbb{R}^L$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

By $\Bbb{R}^L$, I mean the set that is interpreted as $\Bbb{R}$ in $L$, Godel's constructible universe. For concreteness, and to avoid definitional questions about $\Bbb{R}$, I'm looking at the set ${\cal P}(\omega)$ as a proxy. I would think it needs to be countable, since only definable subsets of $\omega$ are being considered, but I don't see how Cantor's theorem would fail here, since $L$ is a model of $\sf{ZFC}$. (Actually, that's a lie: this probably means that there is no injection $f:\omega\to{\cal P}(\omega)^L$ *in $L$*, even if there is one in $V$. I'm still a little hazy on all the details, though.) But the ordinals are in $L$, so $L$ is not itself countable, and there must exist genuinely uncountable elements of $L$. What does the powerset operation (in $L$) do to the cardinality of sets (as viewed in $V$), then?

Answer (score 11):

It is impossible to give a complete answer to this question just in $\sf ZFC$.

For once, it is possible that $V=L$ is true in the model you consider, so in fact $\Bbb R^L=\Bbb R$, so the cardinality is $\aleph_1$.

On the other hand it is possible that the universe is $L[A]$ where $A$ is a set of $\aleph_2$ Cohen reals, in which case $\Bbb R^L$ is still of size $\aleph_1$.

And it is also possible that the universe is $L[G]$ where $G$ is a function which collapses $\omega_1^L$, resulting in having $\Bbb R^L$ as a countable set.

There are other axioms, such as large cardinal axioms (e.g. "$0^\#$ exists") which imply that $\Bbb R^L$ is countable, and one can arrange all sort of crazy tricks, where the result is large or small compared to $\Bbb R$.

One thing is for certain, $|\Bbb R^L|=|\omega_1^L|\in\{\aleph_0,\aleph_1\}$.

Comment: I see your point for most of that; since $L$ is a model of ${\sf ZFC}$, we may not have in fact "escaped" the model at all in our discussion of $V$. But suppose I took appropriate large cardinal axioms which made the powerset operation as weak as possible w.r.t raising the cardinality. Your answer suggests that $\Bbb{R}^L=\aleph_0$ in this case, but (in a slight extension of the original question) what picture do we get of the model universe from this POV? Are the ordinals still absolute? Is ${\sf On}^L$ an ordinal? How big is it? Basically, what is the smallest model of ZFC?

Comment: @Mario: Those are good questions. First we need to make a huge distinction. $L$ is, and will always be, a proper class containing all the ordinals. It is possible that there are set models of $\sf ZFC+\bf V=L$, but when we say $L$ we always mean the proper class inner model. As to the difference between $L$ and $V$, if we assume $\lnot\exists 0^\#$ then Jensen's Covering Lemma tells us that the universe itself is not very far from $L$, even if some cardinals are collapsed, and power sets changed, there's still a good sense to saying that $L$ is close to being $V$ [cont.]

Comment: [..intued] But if we assume that $0^\#$ exists, then in a very good sense we know that $L$ is very small and "thin" compared to the actual universe. The covering lemma has many interesting equivalents (e.g. not calculating successors of singulars correctly). So in some sense $0^\#$ is the tipping point whether or not $V_{\omega+1}$ is "close" to $V_{\omega+1}^L$ or not. In all cases, however, we can say two things: (1) If $M$ is a transitive class containing all the ordinals and a model of $\sf ZF$, then $L\subseteq M$; (2) the smallest well-founded model of $\sf ZFC$ is some $L_\beta$ [cont.]

Comment: [..intued] for some countable ordinal $\beta$. This is the least standard model. But in that model there exists a set which is a non-standard model of $\sf ZFC$. In either cases those are *set models*. And set models and class models are two very different beasts.